# I am getting 500 internal error when giving url as dir/file/file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, web-development-server

When I am trying to give url as https://example.com/dir/file/file then the request is getting into loop and 500 error comes while it should give file does not exists. I am using LAMP Stack. I am hiding .php in my .htaccess

```
## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> # To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
> RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
> ```

You are getting a rewrite-loop (500 error) because the filename you are checking, ie. `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php` isn't necessarily the same as the file you are rewriting to, ie. `$1.php`.

If you request `/dir/file/file` then the `REQUEST_FILENAME` server variable is `<document-root>/dir/file` (no path-info), whereas the captured backreference `$1` is `/dir/file/file`.

Try the following instead:

```
# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

A request for `/dir/file/file` will now fail with a 404, since it is checking that `/dir/file/file.php` exists.

You don't really need to check that the request does not map to a directory before checking that it does map to a file (twice the work), unless you also have directories of the same name and you need the directory to take priority (unlikely).

See also [my answer](https://serverfault.com/a/989351/49157) to the following ServerFault question that goes into more detail:
https://serverfault.com/questions/989333/using-apache-rewrite-rules-in-htaccess-to-remove-html-causing-a-500-error

Comment: ++ as I've also noticed `REQUEST_FILENAME` misbehaving